Why do I get a malformed supported_versions extension at ClientHello when I use openssl s_client?
What's my problem?
I'm doing tests to reach a server using TLS 1.3 with openssl s_client. I've had a lot of troubles figuring out why the server is answering with a fatal error alert and I've finally figured out why that is. One of the TLS extensions sent, specifically the supported_versions one, is missing a couple of bytes and, as expected, the server aborts the connection.
Now, my problem is that I don't understand why my implementation of openssl is malforming that extension. I don't know if I've encountered a bug or if there´s something wrong with my setup.
My setup:
WSL Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (jammy) over Windows 10
OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024)
What did I try?
I've upgraded my WSL Ubuntu to the latest packages and I've also build from source the latest openssl trying to solve my problem but I got the same results.
This is the output from command:
openssl s_client -host <myServerHostName> -port <myServerPort> -cert cer.pem -key client.key -debug -msg -state -tls1_3

CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
>>> TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    16 03 01 00 e0
>>> TLS 1.3, Handshake [length 00e0], ClientHello
    01 00 00 dc 03 03 a6 e8 05 13 21 0e 66 c3 fb c1
    76 c0 b4 48 41 98 ed 96 fa 8d d0 c0 e7 e0 4f ab
    ed 32 37 a0 e5 59 20 f7 1b d5 d9 fe dd 07 93 0b
    a4 66 df 87 ec 56 b1 9e 97 32 8c c1 85 5c a7 e4
    35 07 38 77 e5 8f 53 00 06 13 02 13 03 13 01 01
    00 00 8d 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 16 00
    14 00 1d 00 17 00 1e 00 19 00 18 01 00 01 01 01
    02 01 03 01 04 00 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 17 00
    00 00 0d 00 24 00 22 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08
    08 08 1a 08 1b 08 1c 08 09 08 0a 08 0b 08 04 08
    05 08 06 04 01 05 01 06 01 00 2b 00 03 02 03 04
    00 2d 00 02 01 01 00 33 00 26 00 24 00 1d 00 20
    c8 d3 d9 59 ff f5 33 28 7f 8d 6d b1 d8 4c 60 b5
    dd da ee 0d 3c 4c 14 c0 5c ce 83 5e 88 40 12 50
write to 0x7fffd04fd5d0 [0x7fffd0509700] (229 bytes => 229 (0xE5))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 e0 01 00 00-dc 03 03 a6 e8 05 13 21   ...............!
0010 - 0e 66 c3 fb c1 76 c0 b4-48 41 98 ed 96 fa 8d d0   .f...v..HA......
0020 - c0 e7 e0 4f ab ed 32 37-a0 e5 59 20 f7 1b d5 d9   ...O..27..Y ....
0030 - fe dd 07 93 0b a4 66 df-87 ec 56 b1 9e 97 32 8c   ......f...V...2.
0040 - c1 85 5c a7 e4 35 07 38-77 e5 8f 53 00 06 13 02   ..\..5.8w..S....
0050 - 13 03 13 01 01 00 00 8d-00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02   ................
0060 - 00 0a 00 16 00 14 00 1d-00 17 00 1e 00 19 00 18   ................
0070 - 01 00 01 01 01 02 01 03-01 04 00 23 00 00 00 16   ...........#....
0080 - 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 0d-00 24 00 22 04 03 05 03   .........$."....
0090 - 06 03 08 07 08 08 08 1a-08 1b 08 1c 08 09 08 0a   ................
00a0 - 08 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06-04 01 05 01 06 01 00 2b   ...............+
00b0 - 00 03 02 03 04 00 2d 00-02 01 01 00 33 00 26 00   ......-.....3.&.
00c0 - 24 00 1d 00 20 c8 d3 d9-59 ff f5 33 28 7f 8d 6d   $... ...Y..3(..m
00d0 - b1 d8 4c 60 b5 dd da ee-0d 3c 4c 14 c0 5c ce 83   ..L`.....<L..\..
00e0 - 5e 88 40 12 50                                    ^.@.P

Reading the ClientHello record at this line:
    05 08 06 04 01 05 01 06 01 00 2b 00 03 02 03 04

We have the TLS extension supported_versions. Inspecting it, I found that a couple of lengths are missing.
A valid supported_versions extension must look like this:
        00 2b         Extension supported versions
          00 05         length of extension (5 bytes)
            04            length of list
              03 04         TLS 1.3
              03 03         TLS 1.2

But I have the following malformed extension:
        00 2b         Extension supported versions
          00 ??         length of extension (incomplete)
            ??            length of list (missing)
              03 04         TLS 1.3
              03 03         TLS 1.2

What am I expecting?
I'm expecting a valid supported extensions with the usage of openssl s_client and option -tls1_3

FWIW, that 00 2b 00 03 02 03 04 byte sequence does match the byte sequence in the ClientHello found here:  https://tls13.xargs.org/#client-hello  That same 00 2b 00 03 02 03 04 byte sequence is found 19 times in RFC 8448 - Example Handshake Traces for TLS 1.3  How certain are you that byte sequence is wrong?

I believe 00 2b 00 03 02 03 04 is parsed as 00 2b - supported versions, then 00 03 - three bytes, then  02 - two bytes of versions, then 03 04 - TLSv1.3

"00 2b 00 03 02 03 04" (supported_versions extension) is well-formed. Because the "-tls1_3" flag was specified, only "03 04" (TLSv1.3) was included in the supported_versions extension.
(vi:ins)$ openssl s_client -help
...
 -tls1_3                    Just use TLSv1.3
...

If you try the same command with www.yahoo.com, Yahoo would happily negotiate TLSv1.3.
With the -tls1_3 flag, cipher suites in the ClientHello message just include those applicable to TLSv1.3. TLS 1.2 server or middlebox may not like such messages.
Have you tried the same command without the -tls1_3 flag?
